# Get parent with certain class from child element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use jquery droppable.

When I drop an element I get the element beneath the dropped element:

```
var elementBeneathDroppedElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```

BUT the elementBeneathDroppedElement is just a fragment of the whole div with MULTIPLE divs. It really depends where the user drops his element and what element I get back as the beneath dropped element.

Thats the structure of a typical element on the container where I drop other elements:

```
<div class="refOptionItem" >

    <div class="refOptionItemContent text-center text-uppercase" style="color: @Model.Item1.CssColor">
        <div>
            <img src="@(Model.Item1.IconName)" alt="@Model.Item1.IconName" />
        </div>
        <div>@Model.Item1.Name</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is the image-tag but what I want is the top div with the class "refOptionItem".

I tried this:

```
var topParentDiv = $('.refOptionItem', elementBeneathDroppedElement );
 // restrict to context is not correct I guess
```

How do you search for a parent with a certain class starting from the elementBeneathDroppedElement I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

*Code*

```
var topParentDiv = $(elementBeneathDroppedElement).closest('.refOptionItem');
```

Comment: Sorry it worked! I look at the wrong property not into topParentDiv[0] inside there the outerHTML shows the whole div stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

> Description: Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
var p = $(elementBeneathDroppedElement).parent('.refOptionItem');
```